# keep textarea update automatically on input - all around the world

Tags: javascript, php, server

textarea - automatically update:

```
$('#editor').on('input', function(){
    let story = $(this).val();
    $.post('nts_pro.php', {fn: 'save', args: [story]});
});
```

on server side the above value is stored inside a table or a file system - using `php`

this works excellent in Croatia (my host provider is in Croatia).
in Slovakia - this works but... not always
in Canada - I can say - this doesn't work.

I asked my host provider about mirror servers - and the answer is - we don't have mirror servers.
The same answer from a couple of others hosting companies

So what is the way - on the level of coding or whatever - to keep this functionality all around the world?

Comment: **Doesn't work** Not really very helpful. Do you get errors? Is there anything in the logs to identify what does not work and why it may not be working

Comment: When you say Canada doesn't work, what is it actually doing or saying when it doesn't work as mirrored servers shouldn't be stopping it from working in other countries.

Comment: @imvain2 Dont think OP has mirror servers. Not really sure one would do anything other than make life a lot more complicated keeping them all current anyway

Comment: @RiggsFolly, @i there is no error - at least in console and on php level. Simply the value is not saved on server, sometimes even after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you should look into WebSockets.

Making AJAX calls to server for an update is a bad idea because if multiple people keep making AJAX calls for updates, it will take up all of your resources.

I personally run NodeJS WebSocket server (socket.io) and make all communication via that server.

This allows user to QUICKLY send information and for server to notify ALL connected users about those changes.

Couple of tutorials for Socket.io :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQjiN8Qgs3c

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHbCkikFfDE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75CCxIBs4Ak

Comment: hmm, thanks, I'll try - didn't know about this possibility. But the problem here is not a lot of users in the same time. Max 3 users, till now.

Comment: Depending on your servers speed and resource, sometimes only one user can cause those problems for you. 
The location problem that you addressed is that - further away you are from the server, it will take longer time in general to retrieve information. 

If I got your websites idea right, people are writing inside same textarea and it should update while someone is typing. Websockets are the way to go.